# Issue in CSS style of UpdateProgress

Tags: css, progress-bar, updateprogress

I'm using a Update panel in Asp.net. Im having update progress for which i have set a DIV and set a CSS for it. The issue is when I call it, it will show the Progress bar but i can scroll the window.. I need to make it as a Modal(No Selection possible when progress bar is shown). Is it possible

```
  .Progressbar
{
background-position: center center;
background-color:White;
filter: alpha(opacity=75);
opacity: 0.7;
background-image: url('../images/loading.gif');
background-attachment:fixed;
position:absolute;  
background-repeat: no-repeat;
/*z-index:0;*/
z-index:100;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top:0px;
right:0px;
botton: 0px;
left:0px;
overflow:hidden;}
```

This is the CSS for the DIV tag im using inside the Update Progress. 
If the page is containing data more than the Height of the screen resolution its allowing me to see those contents. 
How can i change it so that when Progress bar is shown nothing will be selectable and even if we SCROLL we this DIV will remain in the Same position(WINDOW) than getting scrolled.

[image: See the image below]

how can i change this issue???

Answer (score 0):

Give a id to your main div(the div containing everything) and set the `z-index` of you main div to `-1` and give `z-index:0` to your body, while update progress and on completion change the `z-index` to `1`.

Comment: I tried. You know.. the problem is with my height. My height is only till the Browsers Bottom. If the content is more than that(height wise), the DIV will be like what you see in the image. Where this progressbar is shown its not allowing me to select anything. But if you scroll the DIV also GOES UP..

Comment: Include all your content into a div, that div contains everything, it's the first and only child element of body. Now, toggle the z-index of this div. You won't see any problem with this approach.